# Dojo > ItemFileWriteStore > How to get only those cells with changes (Not every cell in the row)

Tags: javascript, dojo

Using either `_saveCustom()` or `onSet()`, I can find out when values have changed in an `ItemFileWriteStore`, however, in both cases, I get every cell in the row, even though only 1 cell (for example) has changed.

Anyone know of a way to find only those *cells* that have changed?  Right now, the only thing I can think of is to maintain a separate copy of the data and compare against it.

Answer (score 0):

I firebugged the notification handling and came up with this, which seems to work:

```
store.onSet = function(row, cellName, oldValue, newValue){
    if (oldValue !== newValue){
        alert(cellName + " changed  to: " + newValue);
    }
}
```